# OFFSET and LIMIT expressions scope

Tags: sqlite

I found following limitation(?) in SQLite (3.7.16.2):

Imagine following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (v);
CREATE TABLE t2 (v);
```

If a have a sub-query like this,

```
SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT() FROM t2 WHERE t2.v = t1.v) FROM t1;
```

it works, meaning that in sub-query on `t2` you can refer outer query (on `t1`) columns.

However,

```
SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT() FROM t2 LIMIT t1.v) FROM t1;
```

or

```
SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT() FROM t2 LIMIT 1 OFFSET t1.v) FROM t1;
```

fails with error `Error: no such column: t1.v`.

This means that expressions within `OFFSET` and `LIMIT` clauses can't refer columns from outer queries.

Is this behaviour a limitation on SQLite engine?

Or am I missing some point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed a limitation in all SQLite versions so far.
(`OFFSET`/`LIMIT` is a non-standard extension, so it is not specified whether this should be allowed.)

Comment: Is this a documented limitation or a bug? `LIMIT` allows all types of other expressions like subqueries, so only this specific type of expression is not supported seems odd.

Comment: It is neither documented nor a bug, it's how SQLite happens to be implemented.

Comment: what is different in the expression evaluation code related to `LIMIT` compared to other expression evaluation code?

Comment: The function `computeLimitRegisters()` in `select.c` can create VDBE code only for constant LIMIT/OFFSET values.

Comment: For me, this is a little scratch in the near-perfect SQLite engine... :-(

Comment: @CL, thanks for the extra info.  I'm not that familiar with the source, but it looks like `computeLimitRegisters()` calls `sqlite3ExprCode()` which calls `sqlite3ExprCodeTarget()`.  Isn't this the same method that calculates all other expressions?  So why the difference in `LIMIT` vs other expressions?  I've searched and don't see it.  I'm really curious now.  :-)

Comment: @SamuelNeff Correlated subqueries must be handled differently because the value must be reset for each new subquery execution.